# How to replace end connector on stainless steel hoses

Tags: hoses

[image]How to replace connector on stainless steel garden hose.  Broken connector will not come off and I need to replace entire connector.

Comment: A photo would help in answering the question.

Comment: Most examples are not practical to repair. Can't be 100% certain without seeing what you have, but generally that's the case.

Comment: Is it something like one of these? If it is, maybe the same company sells repair kits. https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=stainless+steel+hoses&hvadid=588601398621&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9000945&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=8909776211323755428&hvtargid=kwd-303130972556&hydadcr=27374_14530471&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_8wznng7sai_e

Comment: I added a photo.  I don’t see how you replace the connector that is stuck now on the broken shut off valve

Comment: Did the connector originally push on with a clicking sound? Or did it screw on?

Comment: The connector screwed on. It was a one valve brass shut off valve.

Answer (score 1):

The picture appears to show a female brass fitting that has jammed on the male hose end. Probably due to [galling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galling), which stainless steel is highly subject to. Brass should be resistant, but it's either galling (stainless steel is good enough at it that it may have overcome the brass) or corrosion products from being left attached in the weather for a long time, at best guess.

[image]

Or is the male end of the hose going into an Aluminum part? That would be a disaster in terms of galling potential, but the fix would be the same. Not *entirely* clear where hose stops and stuck fitting starts.

That should be fixable by carefully cutting the brass fitting to release the  female threads from the male stainless steel threads, without overcutting and damaging the male threads. I don't think replacing the male end of the hose is practical outside of a factory with all the right tooling on this sort of hose.

Before using again, apply anti-sieze compound to the male threads of the hose before assembling to a female fitting.